# How to implement admin interface for drupal7 custom module?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-modules

I am new to Drupal.I am working on creating custom module in drupal7.

I created one review form(contains name,rating,comments fields) in front page.
After user submit this form I stored data in database.I retrived and displayed this data in block.This is what I have done.

But I need admin interface for this module As "the user submitted rating displayed in admin section"   and  "admin need to perform approve,edit,delete operations on user rating".

How to implement this.

Please help me any one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how are you storing the data you collect with your form but my advice is to create content type with fields your form collects. Then, when your form is submitted for storing that data you just have to create new node in your content type. You'll easy find some tutorial explaining how to create new node of some content type programmatically. That way you'll have your submitted data "in the system" so you can user i.e. views module to retrieve you data.

Answer (score 1):

Did you search google? If so, it probably would have directed you to [Creating a module configuration (settings) page](https://www.drupal.org/node/206761)

Answer (score 1):

If i haven't misunderstood your question I think the proper way to achieve this is by adding your module permissions into the drupal permissions system.
You can achieve this by adding to your module the hook_permission

```
function custommodulename_permission() {
return array(
'custommodulename' => array(
  'title' => t('custommodulename'),
  'description' => t('Access URL for custommodulename module.'),
 ),
);
```

Then you can add the admin permission into admin/people/permissions page.